# How to display concatenated string on same

Tags: python, sys

Using following code I want to take two strings, concat them and display them on same line using `sys.stdin.readline()` for input and `sys.stdout.write()` for output.

```
import sys

str1 = sys.stdin.readline()

str2 = sys.stdin.readline()

str3 = str1 + str2

sys.stdout.write(str3)
```

If I print output, it prints on two separate line. Is the method to cancat with `sys` is wrong?

Thank You

Comment: Why are you using `sys.stdout.write` and `sys.stdin.readline` instead of `print` and `input`? That would take care of trailing linefeeds for you, on top of being the normal way of working with standard input and output.

Comment: `str1` ends with a linefeed ('\n'). You can get rid of it with `str1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()`

Comment: I know to use `input()` and `print()`, but I got this question for the competition and it has to be completed using `sys`.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, `str1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()` works. Thank you. Can you post your comment as answer?

Comment: Note that it will also remove leading and trailing whitespaces. If you want to keep them, and only strip the `\n`, use  `str1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n")`

Comment: And who on the earth negated my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to `input` (Python3) or `raw_input` (Python2), `sys.stdin.readline` doesn't remove the newline (`\n') at the end of your string.

You can remove it by using:

```
str1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip("\n") # only strip \n
```

If you want to remove also all leading and trailing whitespace:

```
str1 = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

`strip` acts on both ends of the string. If you only want to remove the trailing whitespace, use `rstrip` (*r* for *right*).

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str for a complete reference of string methods.

Answer (score 2):

The `readline` method returns a string *that includes the line terminator*. One easy way to get rid of that would be to use the retruned string minus its last character:

```
str1 = sys.stdin.readline()[:-1]
```

Another would be to use the string's `rstrip` method to remove any trailing whitespace:

```
str1 = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip()
```

Comment: What is the difference between `strip()` and `rstrip()`

Comment: You are, I hope, aware that you could have answered this question yourself by looking at [Python's on-line documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip). Don't get into [help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/help-vampire/info) habits! `strip` removes whitespace from both ends of a string, `rstrip` only from the right-hand end.